# fopen() don't stop of returning NULL

Tags: c, file, fopen

I have this segment of two functions that should count the number of words of a file.txt. My problem is that `fopen` don't stop of returning me the NULL value, so I can't run the function properly. I look more than one time and I'm sure that I have my file.txt in the folder.

**I expect to return the number of words from texto.txt**

```
int contadorPalabras(char str[]) {
    int k, j;
    k = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (str[k] != '\0') {
        if (str[k] == ' ') {
            j += 1;
            while (str[k + 1] == ' ') {
                k += 1;
            }
        }
        k += 1;
    }
    if (str[0] == ' ') {
        j -= 1;
    }
    if (str[k - 1] == ' ') {
        j -= 1;
    }
    return (j + 1);
}

int palabras_en_txt() {
    char cad[10000];
    int total, j;
    j = 0;
    FILE *fichero;
    fichero = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
    if (fichero == NULL) {
        printf("Hubo un problema en la apertura del archivo especificado.\n");
        return 404;
    }

    while (feof(fichero) == 0) {
        cad[j] = fgetc(fichero);
        j += 1;
    }
    fclose(fichero);
    printf("%s", cad[j]);

    total = contadorPalabras(cad);

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: When `fopen()` returns `null` you should check `errno` for the reason, then fix it. Most likely your working directory is not where the file is, so you should use a full pathname.

Comment: ... or make sure the current working directory of the program is the folder where the texto.txt file is. This totally depends on your environnement/IDE/OS/the_way you_run_the_program etc.

Answer (score 4):

One of two things is possible:

- `texto.txt` does not live in the same directory as your executable; as an experiment, use an absolute path on the file name - `"/path/to/texto.txt"`;
- Your executable not have permission to read `texto.txt` - check the file permissions.

When `fopen` fails it will set `errno`, from which you can display an error message:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
fichero = fopen( "texto.txt", "r" );
if ( fichero == NULL )
{
  perror( "failed to open texto.txt" );
  ...
}
```

This will give you some information as to why the operation failed ("file not found" or "permission denied" or something else).

Finally, do not use `feof` as your loop condition - it only returns true *after* you've tried to read past the end of the file. You should test the return value of `fgetc` instead:

```
int c;
while ( j < 10000 && (c = fgetc( fichero )) != EOF )
{
  cad[j] = c;
  ...
}
```

Comment: You might also hint that `j` should be tested against the length of the `cad` array to avoid a buffer overflow and a null terminator must be set after the last character stored into it

Comment: @chqrlie: D'oh.  I'll add that condition to the code.  I'll offer up being two weeks out of coronary bypass surgery as my excuse.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you got a close call at 58, but glad you are recovering.  Are you still actively programming ?

Comment: @chqrlie: Yeah, still have a job, just on leave until I'm fully recovered.  *Quintuple* bypass, including one 100% blockage where the cardiologist said "I don't understand how that vein is still working."  Miracle I hadn't had a heart attack yet.  So, yeah.

Comment: I worked on an image analysis software in the '90s to assess the stenosis level of coronary arteries... Quite amazing you still have both ventricules fully functional.  Best wishes !

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- when the file cannot be opened, you should issue an error message documenting the cause for the failure. You can use `perror() or` strerror(errno)` for this purpose. This will help track down your problem.
- the loop `while (feof(fichero) == 0)` is incorrect. You should store the return value of `fgetc(fichero) in an` int`and compare it to`EOF`. Furthermore, you should check that` j` does not exceed the array length and you should set a null terminator after the last character read from the file:

  int c;
  size_t j = 0;
  while ((c = fgetc(fichero)) != EOF) {
  if (j < sizeof(cad) - 1)
  cad[j++] = c;
  }
  cad[j] = '\0';
- `contadorPalabras` only tests for strings of spaces. You should also check for TABs and newlines that may separate words.  The macro `isspace()` from `<ctype.h>` can be used to test for all white space characters.
- there is no need to store the whole file in memory for this task: you can keep the last and the current character read from the file to count the transitions from non-word to word.
- returning 404 in case of error is humorous but inappropriate as this is a valid count of words.

Here is a modified version:

```
int palabras_en_txt(void) {
    int total = 0;
    int last, c;
    FILE *fichero = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
    if (fichero == NULL) {
        perror("Hubo un problema en la apertura del archivo especificado");
        return -1;
    }

    last = '\n';
    while ((c = fgetc(fichero)) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(last) && !isspace(c))
            total += 1;
        last = c;
    }
    fclose(fichero);
    printf("words: %d\n", total);
    return total;
}
```